# Search bar showing results of "e" and "é" at the same time

Tags: ios7, dictionary, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar implemented and working correctly. The only problem is, if i type in the search bar the letter " e " it will only show me words starting with the letter " e " correctly, neglecting all the words starting/having the letter " é ". I made sure all my queries concerning loading the database into NSMutableArray are UTF-8 encoded correctly. But the problem is, how can i show results of " e " and " é " when the user presses " e ". Practically like all the french dictionaries work!

 This is how i filter the words when the user presses any letter :

```
for (Author* author in theauthorsLoadedFinal2)

{           
    NSRange nameRange = [author.name  rangeOfString:text options:NSAnchoredSearch ];

    NSRange descriptionRange = [author.genre rangeOfString:text options:NSAnchoredSearch];
    if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound || descriptionRange.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        [filteredTableData addObject:author];
                  }


}
```

}

Many Thanks

Comment: Look for `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch`.

Comment: @Larme thank you for your reply, but how do i implement it

Comment: @Larme thank you it helped !!! post it as an answer and i will accept it :)

Comment: I just gave you the key word to look for. I didn't actually give you the code or how to use it (I never had to use it myself). It was just a tip for your own research. So don't mind about posting yourself the answer and how you used it (code).

Comment: @Larme sure thing i will, it was the best tip ever!, but one more question, do u know the equivalent of this function in Windows 8 app C# ?

Comment: That's should be another question, but look for Diacritic and C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Larme's tip, THe answer was pretty simple ! for all of the future encounters of this problem, use the following code :

```
NSRange nameRange = [author.name  rangeOfString:text options:NSAnchoredSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch];

NSRange descriptionRange = [author.genre rangeOfString:text options:NSAnchoredSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch];
```